# Dynamic update Query in sql server. i need to pass value in variable but this give me error when i execute the cammand

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Query IS

```
WHILE @ChangedColumnCount > 0 -- Countdown
BEGIN
    SELECT @CurrentFieldName = '['+[FieldName]+']' , @ChangedFieldName = '['+[PreviousField]+']'
        FROM @UpdateColumn
        WHERE id=@ChangedColumnCount
        Declare @UpdateColumnQuery nvarchar(max)
        set @UpdateColumnQuery = 'Update CustomObjectMappingTable set ObjectFieldName = ' + @ChangedFieldName + ' where CustomObjectID = 1072 AND ObjectFieldName = ' + @CurrentFieldName
        print @UpdateColumnQuery
        EXEC(@UpdateColumnQuery)

    SET @ChangedColumnCount = @ChangedColumnCount - 1; -- Countdown
END
```

its give me error when i run the command

> Update CustomObjectMappingTable set ObjectFieldName = [StudyHistory]
> where CustomObjectID = 1072 AND ObjectFieldName = [Qualifications] Msg
> 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Invalid column name 'Qualifications'.

anyone help me ? remmber i need to pass value in variable but its gives me error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `@UpdateColumnQuery` to:

```
SET @UpdateColumnQuery = 'UPDATE CustomObjectMappingTable SET ObjectFieldName = ''' + @ChangedFieldName + ''' WHERE CustomObjectID = 1072 AND ObjectFieldName = ''' + @CurrentFieldName + ''';';
```

Resulting dynamic SQL:

```
UPDATE CustomObjectMappingTable SET ObjectFieldName = '[StudyHistory]' WHERE CustomObjectID = 1072 AND ObjectFieldName = '[Qualifications]';
```

Your update/where **string** values need to be in single quotes.